# PHP: Replace certain parts of string with array values

Tags: php, regex, arrays, curly-brackets

I want to replace values in a string if a particular string exists in an array.

```
$str = 'My name is {{name}}. I live in {{city}}. I love to {{hobby}}. {{ops...}}';

$array = array(
    'name' => '010 Pixel',
    'city' => 'USA',
    'hobby' => 'code',
    'email' => 'xyz@abc.com'
);
```

I want to replace {{name}} with the value of name in $array. If the string inside curly brackets doesn't exist in the $array then let that string stay as it is.

Expected result:

```
My name is 010 Pixel. I live in USA. I love to code. {{ops...}}
```

The reason I'm concern about this is, when any value coming from form contains any {{field-name}} then it shouldn't get replaced. I want to replace only what is set in $str.

Comment: This is why I like StackOverflow, here we have working 4 answers with all different approaches !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is **[strtr](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php)** function.

```
$str = 'My name is {{name}}. I live in {{city}}. I love to {{hobby}}. {{ops...}}';

$array = array(
    '{{name}}' => '010 Pixel',
    '{{city}}' => 'USA',
    '{{hobby}}' => 'code',
    '{{email}}' => 'xyz@abc.com'
);
echo strtr($str, $array);
```

Comment: What if my array values are coming from $_POST?

Comment: @010Pixel Wrap `{{}}` to your array index should not be hard work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?
$str = 'My name is {{name}}. I live in {{city}}. I love to {{hobby}}. {{ops...}}';

$array = array(
    'name' => '010 Pixel',
    'city' => 'USA',
    'hobby' => 'code',
    'email' => 'xyz@abc.com'
);

if (preg_match_all("/{{(.*?)}}/", $str, $m)) {
  foreach ($m[1] as $i => $varname) {
    $str = str_replace($m[0][$i], $array[$varname], $str);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have already tried this but I want some more simple way haha. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = 'My name is {{name}}. I live in {{city}}. I love to {{hobby}}. {{ops...}}';

$array = array(
    'name' => '010 Pixel',
    'city' => 'USA',
    'hobby' => 'code',
    'email' => 'xyz@abc.com'
);

$callback = function($match) use ($array) {
    if (array_key_exists($match[1], $array)) {
        return $array[$match[1]];
    } else {
        return $match[0];
    }
};

$str = preg_replace_callback('/\{\{(.*?)\}\}/', $callback, $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [preg_replace_callback](https://www.php.net/preg_replace_callback) works-

```
$str = 'My name is {{name}}. I live in {{city}}. I love to {{hobby}}. {{ops...}}';
$array = array(
    'name' => '010 Pixel',
    'city' => 'USA',
    'hobby' => 'code',
    'email' => 'xyz@abc.com'
);
$res = preg_replace_callback('/\{{2}(.*?)\}{2}/',
        function($matches)use($array){
            $key = $matches[1];
            if(isset($array[$key])){
                return "{{".$array[$key]."}}";
            };
            return $matches[0];
        },
        $str);
var_dump($res);
/*
    OUTPUT-
    string 'My name is {{010 Pixel}}. I live in {{USA}}. I love to {{code}}. {{ops...}}' (length=75)
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = preg_replace('/{{([a-zA-Z\_\-]*?)}}/ie','$array',$str);
```

Hope this could help

Comment: Using the `e` modifier you can have any PHP expression in the replacement part of `preg_replace`.

Comment: Can you please show me a demo of this? It gives me some errors.

Comment: `/e` modifier is deprecated. Use `preg_replace_callback` instead.